# Jave process getInputStream from subprocess

Tags: java, process, inputstream, outputstream

I used processbuilder fork a sub process and i want to get output of subprocess.So i use the getInputStream of process to get the output of subprocess.I find parent process can read the output from subprocess only when the subprocess exit or the Std.out of subprocess closed.

System.out.flush() by subprocess  doesn't work.

But i need to get output many times. How can i do in this occasion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code, and knowing exactly what is in your subprocess in particular, it's harder to help. Here is an example that works for me, where the subprocess prints out text, waits for three seconds, and then prints out more text. On my machine (Java 6 on Windows XP), I see the initial text, the pause, and then the remaining text - all before the subprocess exits.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;


public class TestProcessBuilder
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            String threeCommands[] = 
                { "cmd", "/c", 
                    "dir", // prints out text 
                    "&&",
                    "ping", "127.0.0.1", "-n", "3", ">", "nul", // waits 3 seconds
                    "&&",
                    "dir" // prints out more text
                };
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(threeCommands);
            builder.directory(new File("C://"));
            builder.redirectErrorStream();

            Process subProcess = builder.start();

            // this reads from the subprocess's output stream
            BufferedReader subProcessInputReader = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(subProcess.getInputStream()));

            String line = null;
            while ((line = subProcessInputReader.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);

            subProcessInputReader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Now I have changed to output into a temp file,but i really want to know how do the two streams connect together.I think the parent process can't access the memory of sub process.So does the communication between the two processes support by OS.Say, sub process outputs its data into an memory area allocated by OS？Then the parent process read it from that memory.I am curious about how does it work.